# Subsonic 3 Class Generation not working

Tags: subsonic3

I have a Website Project in my Visual Studio 2008. I added a Class Library so I can do my Subsonic Class Generation there and reference it via the project. However when I run the class generation it doesn't complete. It does almost nothing. I'll post what gets generated in the ActiveRecord.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using SubSonic.DataProviders;
using SubSonic.Extensions;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using SubSonic.Schema;
using System.Collections;
using SubSonic;
using SubSonic.Repository;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace Test.Data
{
```

That is all it generated...
What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a connection string error. Or, at least, that's what I got when I had my connection string wrong.

What is displayed in Visual Studio build errors?

Comment: How embarrassing. I added the connectionstring to the AppConfig section not the ConnectionString section. Thanks for diverting my attention there :)